# Steam game does not use all available CPU power

Tags: lubuntu, games, steam, cpu, optimization

When I quit a Steam game today I noticed on CPU Usage Monitor widget graph that it did not run on 100% CPU load which came as a surprise considering that simply scrolling [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) in Firefox uses half of my netbook's CPU power and that the game – running on roughly 15-20 FPS – is barely playable with detail level set to minimum.

Is there a way to give the game more CPU power? My OS in Lubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be a problem of CPU, but video card or available RAM size. Actually some games are poorly optimized and even setting the lowest quality may still require a lot of resources. Also, if you have multicore CPU, it might be that game can't utilize more than one (or two) cores - it's a known issue that can't be helped.